# Suppress Artifactory plugin deployment stage (resolution only)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

Is there a way to suppress the "deployment" stage of the Jenkins Artifactory plugin? Background:

My shop uses the the plugin in the conventional manner on some jobs, ie for snapshot and release builds that are then pushed to an Artifactory repo.

I'm also using it for a few non-build-type jobs simply for binary resolution, in order to get third party and internal helper *.jar libs out of Artifactory so we can stop using SVN as a poor man's binary repo. And that works like a charm. But there's an odd side effect in that the plugin still wants to publish *something* to Artifactory:

[image: Build console showing Artifactory resolution and deploy phases]

Right now I'm mitigating this side effect by pointing to a seldom-used Artifactory repo for the "deployment" and using the build retention params to clean up older builds from that repo:

[image: Plugin Discard old builds settings]

It's not a huge deal as you get a build in Artifactory with no artifacts, but if there's a way to suppress this entirely without a lot of hackery that would make the job build cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Good grief, I need to check my eye prescription. The checkbox to disable publishing is right above the two pictured above.

[image: Checkbox to disable deploy stage]